# Вставить символ в строку PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Есть строка типа:

< br />1 Текст 132 текст текст. < br />2 Текст текст 456 текст. < br />3 Текст текст текст 789. ...

Нужно прогнать через PHP что бы получилось:

< br />1. Текст 123 текст текст. < br />2. Текст текст 456 текст. < br />3. Текст текст текст 789. ...

То есть поставить точку после цифры которая расположена после тега < br />

Помогите это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '< br />1 Текст 132 текст текст. < br />2 Текст текст 456 текст. < br />3 Текст текст текст 789. ...';

$str = preg_replace('~(?<=/>)\d+(?=\h)~', '$0.', $str);

echo $str;
```

Результат:

```
< br />1. Текст 132 текст текст. < br />2. Текст текст 456 текст. < br />3. Текст текст текст 789. ...
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо большое, Вы очень помогли.